# Can a destroyed earth reform into another habitable planet?

Tags: planet, earth, planetary-formation, planetary-science

Let's say a planet-sized object collide with earth, disintegrate it, then reform at the same orbit as earth. Will it eventually formed into a habitable, life-supporting planet with living organism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. You are imagining a collision far greater than the one which formed the moon.

Such a collision will drive off many of the volatiles (water and gases) into space, where they would get carried away by the solar wind.  Thus the rock and metal that could  re-form would be lacking in water, nitrogen, and CO<sub>2</sub>

Without water and the building blocks of organic chemistry, there is no life.  On Earth, the water was brought to Earth by later asteroid collisions.

Even if an atmosphere and oceans did reform, we don't know how likely it is that life would spontaneously develop. We only have one example of life in the universe - we don't know how common or rare it is on other planets.